# Docker 'failed to setup, token credentials missing'

Tags: docker

I'm trying to build the 'rss2twitter' container with a specific flag needed to get it working. Since running:

`docker run rss **--feed=rssfeed.xml**`

does not work because it is trying to execute the command i append to it, I tried to add the command in to the CMD variable in the Dockerfile like so: 
`CMD ["/srv/rss2twitter -f=rssfeed.xml"]`.

Running Docker run gives me the following output based on the addition above:

```
execute "/srv/rss2twitter -f=rssfeed.xml"
rss2twitter - master-17ddbb0-20200212T02:46:34
2020/02/19 03:58:06 PANIC failed to setup, token credentials missing
2020/02/19 03:58:06 PANIC failed to setup, token credentials missing
```

When I run the Docker file without the addition of `-f=rssfeed.xml` it gives me the following output:

```
execute "/srv/rss2twitter"
rss2twitter - master-17ddbb0-20200212T02:46:34
the required flag `-f, --feed' was not specified
```

Any idea how I can fix this? Is it possible to specify non-docker args when running `Docker run` to pass it through to the image?

Any help is appreciated.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM umputun/baseimage:buildgo-latest as build

WORKDIR /build/rss2twitter
ADD . /build/rss2twitter

# run tests
RUN cd app && go test -mod=vendor ./...

RUN \
    version=$(/script/git-rev.sh) && \
    echo "version=$version" && \
    go build -mod=vendor -o rss2twitter -ldflags "-X main.revision=${version} -s -w" ./app

FROM umputun/baseimage:app-latest

COPY --from=build /build/rss2twitter/rss2twitter /srv/rss2twitter
RUN \
    chown -R app:app /srv && \
    chmod +x /srv/rss2twitter

WORKDIR /srv

CMD ["/srv/rss2twitter"]
ENTRYPOINT ["/init.sh"]
```

Comment: Can you include your Dockerfile in the question?  It seems likely at least that there's an ENTRYPOINT line that matters as well.

Comment: I added the Dockerfile in the post. This is the original from the repository and not my edited version with the '-f' flag.

Comment: @DavidMaze is there something I can do with the ENTRYPOINT?

Answer (score 0):

Solution is actually really simple. Use multiple services in the docker-compose.yml file.

Like so:

```
version: '2'
services:
  rss2twitter_nummer_1:
    build: .
    image: umputun/rss2twitter:latest
    container_name: rss2twitter_nummer_1
    hostname: rss2twitter
    restart: always
    logging: &default_logging
      driver: json-file
      options:
        max-size: "10m"
        max-file: "5"
    environment:
      - FEED=feed
      - TWI_CONSUMER_KEY=
      - TWI_CONSUMER_SECRET=
      - TWI_ACCESS_TOKEN=
      - TWI_ACCESS_SECRET=
      - "TEMPLATE={{.Title}} - {{.Link}} #mytag"
    # command: ["/srv/rss2twitter", "--dry"]
  rss2twitter_nummer_2:
    build: .
    image: umputun/rss2twitter:latest
    container_name: rss2twitter_nummer_2
    hostname: rss2twitter
    restart: always
    environment:
      - FEED=
      - REFRESH=1m
      - TWI_CONSUMER_KEY=
      - TWI_CONSUMER_SECRET=
      - TWI_ACCESS_TOKEN=
      - TWI_ACCESS_SECRET=
      - "TEMPLATE={{.Title}} - {{.Link}} #mytag"
    # command: ["/srv/rss2twitter", "--dry"]
```

By copying and pasting the same configuration but changing the container_name and other properties, it spins up multiple containers with different properties.